# CDI - Injecting Classes at runtime

Tags: java, java-ee-6, cdi

I'm working on a project, where it is needed to load some classes at runtime. The classes to load are parts of CDI-Containers and have to be able to inject some stuff. The "loading class" itself is a part of a CDI-Container as well.

Now comes my problem. It is possible to load and instantiate any class via reflection, but in this case it would not be possible for the classes to be loaded to get anything injected. So it is needed to get an instance of these classes as it would be internally done by the server like when we would use the annotation @javax.inject.Inject.

Is there any way to load the classes of another CDI-container in a way that they can still work with Injections (otherwise it would not make any sense^^)? Maybe there is any kind of Class which is responsible for for handling all of these classes so that I can simply tell it the name of the class to load (as I would do it with reflections)... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the BeanManager API to query and laod contextual references based on bean types.

Answer (score 0):

Review your design carefully, as it sounds like you're entering into "procedural style" programming rather than OO. This is likely the first of many problems with your design you're likely to encounter.

I have an idea that might work though; can you make these classes implement a certain interface? If they do, you can use normal @Inject annotations in your code with the interface, then stuff the class implementation into a /lib directory on a server.  This, combined with CDI alternatives may be able to get you what you want.

A better approach may be to use reflection and some kind of factory...